# Keep less files of Bootstrap in productions site after compiling?

Tags: 7, theming

i'm new to Bootstrap, Drupal and Subthemeing so maybe this question is a bit noob. ;-)
I did a Subtheme for Bootstrap 3-Base-Theme with the local bootstrap-files etc. Makes completely sense for developing. But when i'm finished with editing and compiled my styles.css it doesn't make sense to upload also the less-files to my webserver as they are no longer needed, are they? (I just keep them local for developement)

I'm not so sure about the js files, those are still referenced at the info-file.
But i keep thinking that one could drop the less-folder - do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can drop the less-folder on the production site.  It is only used as source for compiling the css files.  If you do that on the local dev-site, they're never used on the production site.

Comment: You can use the less file to integrate your module with the bootstrap theme

Answer (score 2):

Technically you will not need the less files on your production unless you need to Drupal to modify your theme. For instance, if you are integrating the color module that with your theme to allow administrators user to change the colors of the theme using the color module. You need the less files and you need to use [less](https://www.drupal.org/project/less) module. Otherwise you **don't need them less files on your production site.**